# the parent dialog can move

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-xp

I want prevent the parent dialog, not move.
when dialog  process data (17s) i can move the parent dialog to anywhere.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question a bit? Can the user currently move the window, and is that what you want to prevent?

Comment: Is your problem that you're processing data in the foreground, which is causing your UI to lock up and preventing you from being able to move the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the title bar of the window by removing the title text and setting the `ControlBox`, `MaxmimizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` properties to `false`.

I would however think twice before doing this; there are *very* few things that annoy me as much as a user, as windows that position themselves topmost at the center of the screen, with no option to move them away to keep on working on something else.

Comment: I'm fairly sure he meant the complete opposite, right now everything is frozen.  It is a completely unreadable question though.

Comment: @Hans: yes, that might very well be the case. The question is rather ambiguous.